# Render chunks as html

Tags: r, r-markdown

I'm trying to generate markdown documents for a gitlab wiki using rmarkdown. This all works fine I would however like to include some htmlwidgets (e.g. leaflet and reactable) this would allow for extra interactive visualizations. I have the following rmarkdown file:

````
---
always_allow_html: yes
output:
  md_document:
    variant: gfm
---

# normal plot works fine
```{r map}
plot(1:3)
` ``

# renders as an image and not as a html table
```{r}
require(reactable)
r<-reactable(data.frame(1:4,4:1))
r
` ``

# again renders as an image

```{r}
require(leaflet)
leaflet()
` ``
````

This however renders both the leaflet and reactable as an image I would rather include html in my markdown. I have tried to generate the html and then use `output='asis'` but was not able to get it work. This is now the resulting document:

```
# normal plot works fine

` `` r
plot(1:3)
` ``

![](tmp_files/figure-gfm/map-1.png)<!-- -->

# renders as an image and not as a html table

` `` r
require(reactable)
` ``

    ## Loading required package: reactable

` `` r
r<-reactable(data.frame(1:4,4:1))
r
` ``

![](tmp_files/figure-gfm/unnamed-chunk-1-1.png)<!-- -->

# again renders as an image

` `` r
require(leaflet)
` ``

    ## Loading required package: leaflet

` `` r
leaflet()
` ``

![](tmp_files/figure-gfm/unnamed-chunk-2-1.png)<!-- -->
```

Note i inserted spaces in the back-ticks for visualization purposes

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get HTMLwidgets to be displayed in a nonHTML file format, Does using `output: html_document` render your desired output?

output to .md file, using `output: md_document`

[image]

output to .html document, using `output: html_document`

[image]

using the code below for a simple reproducible example.

````
---
always_allow_html: yes
output: html_document
---


# renders as an image and not as a html table
```{r}
require(leaflet)
m <- leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>%  # Add default OpenStreetMap map tiles
  addMarkers(lng=174.768, lat=-36.852, popup="The birthplace of R")
m  # Print the map
```
````